# Horizontal and vertical swipe in android using multidimensional array

Tags: android, swipe, android-pageradapter

I am a newbie in Android and currently developing an app in which there should be integration of Horizontal and vertical swipe simultaneously. The horizontal swipe should result into previous and next images. The vertical swipe should result into language change of the same image which is displayed currently on screen. Both the swipes should be synced with each other. I tried using different PagerAdapters for each language and the integration of horizontal and vertical swipe is done successfully. But the big problem is they are not in sync with each other. What is the way I can sync them successfully? Or any other way to implement this functionality?

Thanks in advance.